# I want to Integrate a button onto my website such that it deletes and creates new cookies for a specific website

Tags: javascript, web, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to make a html script along with js such that it modifies the cookies of a specific website, Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [repro] of what you have tried so far. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a extension you could use https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/ to get the other websites cookies and deleting them, using chrome.cookies.getAll and chrome.cookies.remove

Comment: It's not exactly an extension, But sure, Let's say it's an extension. But I want it to not only remove the cookies of a specific site, But also create new values that I specify..
However, What I'd like to do is integrate it into my website.

Comment: You would need to setup messaging between the website and the extension https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage